# .NET Regular Expression to capture placeholders with optional attributes

Tags: .net, regex, placeholder

I am trying to use regex to identify specific placeholders in a text file.
Every placeholder starts and ends with a %.
The first word after opening % is the placeholdername, that *can* have an optional attribute (think of non-default formatting properties).

Some samples are:

%MyVariable%  -->  desired output is Name=MyVariable , Attribute=''
%MyVariable:uppercase%  -->  desired output is Name=MyVariable , Attribute='uppercase'
%MyVariable:maxlen(20)%  -->  desired output is Name=MyVariable , Attribute='maxlen(20)'
%MyVariable:words(1,2)%  -->  desired output is Name=MyVariable , Attribute='words(1,2)'

Could please anyone help me in building a correct regexp to accomplish this task?

I am using C# and .NET framework v4.0

Thank you

Comment: `^%[*]|[*:*]%$` I suppose is a starting point, though technically the first class would overrule the second anyway...

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html is such a great reference for this, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following pattern will catch every placeholder for you:

```
%(?<name>\w+)(?<attribute>:.*?)?%
```

Retrieve values by group names: *name* and *attribute*.

Example:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"%(?<name>\w+)(?<attribute>:.*?)?%");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var name = match.Groups["name"].Value;
    var attribute = match.Groups["attribute"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(
        string.Format("Name={0}, Attribute='{1}'", name, attribute));
}
```

Explanation: pattern starts and ends with `%` as in your placeholder. Inside we define two groups with names using syntax `(?<group_name>some_pattern_here)`. First group catches all alphanumeric characters with `\w+`, there should be at least 1 character. The second group catches all symbols until `%` using `.*?`. Group may be present or not, so we put `?` after it. That's it. Visually it looks like that:

```
%           MyVariable                 :  words(1,2)     %
% (?<name>     \w+     ) (?<attribute> :     .*?     )?  %
```

Please read regex [reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx) to understand all special characters.

Comment: thanks, it is working as expected. could you please explain it in detail, because I'm trying to learn how regexps work...

Comment: @Genesio, I've added some explanation for you.